# How to add Like/Unlike functionality in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

If I enter the values manually in database for like then I can view it on the wall but I do not know how to insert value programatically on clicking 'like'. 
The query which i would like to get fired on clicking 'like' (which is in every row below msg) is  `"insert into tbl_like (ScrapId,FromId,LikeStatus) values(A*,sessionUserID,1)";`

A* = this must be the Scrapid of that particular row in which like was clicked.

Database Table:
Scrap_Table:
ScrapId | FromId | ToId | msg

Like_table:

LikeId | ScrapId | FromId | LikeStatus

Source Code:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridViewUserScraps" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                GridLines="None" Width="100%" ShowHeader="False" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#A5A5A5"
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" DataKeyNames="ScrapId" 
                OnItemCommand="CommandLinkClicked">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='<%#getUserHREF(Container.DataItem)%>'>
                                            <img align="middle" src='<%#getSRC(Container.DataItem)%>' border="0" width="50px" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div align="justify">
                                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Message")%>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Posted On: &nbsp;</span>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSendDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SendDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                            <br />
                           <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" 
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
                                CommandName="LikeCmd">Like</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server">unlike</asp:LinkButton>--%>

                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>Like</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server"  CommandName="unlike" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>unlike</asp:LinkButton>



                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllike" runat="server" Text="likes:"></asp:Label>
                           <%-- <asp:Label ID="lbllikecount" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>--%>


                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Controls_GetUserScraps.abc((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />
                          <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# WebPageName.StaticMethodName((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />--%>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
DataBaseClass dbClass = new DataBaseClass();
public DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

        GetUserScraps(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
    }
}
public void GetUserScraps(int Id)
{

    string getUserScraps = "SELECT u.Id as UserId,u.firstname,u.ImageName,s.FromId,s.ToId,s.Message,s.SendDate,s.ID as ScrapId FROM [User] as u, Scrap as s WHERE u.Id=s.FromId AND s.ToId='" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() + "'";
  //string getlikes = "select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid='"+<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId")%>+"'";
  //  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId")%>


    dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(getUserScraps);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewUserScraps.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewUserScraps.DataBind();
    }
}

public string getUserHREF(object sURL)
{
    DataRowView dRView = (DataRowView)sURL;
    string Id = dRView["UserId"].ToString();
    return ResolveUrl("~/UserDetails.aspx?Id=" + Id);
}

public string getSRC(object imgSRC)
{
    DataRowView dRView = (DataRowView)imgSRC;
    string ImageName = dRView["ImageName"].ToString();
    if (ImageName == "NoImage")
    {
        return ResolveUrl(@"~/Site_Images/image_missing.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        return ResolveUrl("~/UserImage/" + dRView["ImageName"].ToString());
    }
}

public static int abc(int scrpid)
{

    string getlikes = "select COUNT(*) from tbl_like inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid='"+scrpid+"'";

    dboperation dbo = new dboperation();
    int a = dbo.GetLikesMethod(getlikes);

    return a;
}


protected void CommandLinkClicked(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var scrapId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "like":
            var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString); //your connection string
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_like (ScrapId,FromId,LikeStatus) values(@scrapId,@sessionUser,1)");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scrapId", scrapId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionUser", Session["UserId"]);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            break;
        case "unlike":
            //do stuff
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error you recieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `OnItemCommand` event to your grid to handle clicks on link buttons. Also both of link buttons must have `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` set.

Change yours html as follows:

```
<asp:GridView .... OnRowCommand="GridViewRowCommand">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnklike" runat="server" CommandName="like" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>Like</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkunlike" runat="server"  CommandName="unlike" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScrapId")%>'>unlike</asp:LinkButton>

</asp:GridView>
```

And this is event in code behind:

```
protected void GridViewRowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var scrapId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "like" : 
                using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection_string")) //your connection string
                {
                   var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_like (ScrapId,FromId,LikeStatus) values(@scrapId,@sessionUser,1)");
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scrapId", scrapId);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionUser", Session[User]); 
                   cmd.Connection = con;
                   con.Open();
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                break;
        case "unlike" : 
                //do stuff
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i did what you told me to but, when i click 'like', nothing happens. I applied breakpoint, but when i click like it just takes me to the top of the page. See my edit (code behind)

Comment: You are missing this: `<asp:GridView .... OnItemCommand="CommandLinkClicked">` also your `CommandName`s are different than my so change your code behind as well (`case "like"` to  `case "LikeCmd"`

Comment: is it because i copy pasted your code behind instead of generating even through doublecliking on event on property window?

Comment: You do not have to generate that event through designer, just add this `OnItemCommand="CommandLinkClicked"` to grid tag :)

Comment: if you place breakpoint in event handler in code behind something happens?

Comment: I applied breakpoint on commandlinkcliked but when i click on like absolutely nothing happens, it does not even take me to visual studio it just takes me to the top of the page

Comment: Sorry my mistake! `GridView` does not have `OnItemCommand`! Change it back to `OnRowCommand` -> see my edits, I changed my code. Check if it works now.

Comment: I have this wall which is similar to orkut, in future i would like to have wall similar to facebook, i.e one where people can comment on posts (comments within comments) do you have any reference to such tutorial? Just sayin!